# How to use variables in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to store Cypress element in variable and re-use it instead of calling `get()` again.

---

**My first unsuccessful attempt**:

```js
// works
const wrap = cy.get(`wrapSelector`)
wrap.should('be.visible')

// works
const input = wrap.find(`input`)
input.should('be.focused');
input.type(string);

// wrap is now `input` (line 6) instead of `wrapSelector` (line 2)
const button = wrap.find('button').click();
// @error: button not found in `input`
```

---

So I've read Cypress closures and **I've tried using `then()`**. But it returns jQuery object.

```js
cy.get(`someSelector`).then($wrap=>{
    // now I would like to test $wrap 
    // but $wrap is now jQuery object so I can't do this:
    $wrap.should('be.visible')
    // ... some code
})
```

---

It could be working if I would use **whole selector** with children but I am not sure if it's best practice

```js
cy.get(`wrapSelector`).should('be.visible')
cy.get(`wrapSelector input`).should('be.focused')
cy.get(`wrapSelector input`).type(string);
cy.get(`wrapSelector button`).click()
// works
```

---

I know that I can test jQuery object too (for example with `expect()`) but I would like to keep using `should()`. What is the best practice when I would like to re-use some already fetched elements? Ideal solution on this example would be the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using **aliases** as mentioned by Cypress here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context

because of the use of promises, Cypress methods do not return values directly. Aliasing allows you to:

```js
cy.get(element).as("myAlias")
this.myAlias // works
cy.get("@myAlias") // works
```

Comment: I've seen this example but they are implementing `as()` in `before()`. If I try to set alias inside of `it()` then `this.myAlias` throws `Trying to get myAlias of undefined`. But `cy.get("@myAlias")` seems working.

Comment: You should generally use `cy.get("@thing")` rather than the `this` syntax anyways. `this` can create confusion and errors with many elements (arrow functions, callbacks, events, etc.)

Comment: Very well explained. One more thing... As long as `get()` returns `Promise`. Can I be absolutely sure that `cy.get(element).as("myAlias")` is being fetched before `cy.get("@myAlias")` or there is chance that `cy.get("@myAlias")` is going to be undefined?

Comment: If you run two `cy.get` one after the other, the second one will start only once the first one is done. So if the first one defines the alias, either: it gets the alias and then moves on, or the tests fails because the first get failed. So normally you won't have any issue